# pyenv + virtualenv not finding deluge

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I'm trying to use deluge from a virtualenv build with PYENV.
For this purpose, I used pyenv to build a python 2.7.9.
I've set **pyenv global** to 2.7.9 and then installed the deluge package with:

apt-get install deluged deluge-console

Everything went fine, but when I try to do :

import deluge

it gives ImportError.

A pip freeze from inside 2.7.9 enviroment correctly display the deluge package:

```
spadazz@Deluger:~/.pyenv/versions/2.7.9$ pip freeze
apt-xapian-index==0.44
chardet==2.0.1
command-not-found==0.2.44
deluge==1.3.11
```

Doing a check with dpkg -l on ubuntu installed packages for deluge, I can see that deluge python package can be found at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, so adding this path to python sys.path, allows me to manually import the package.

My problem is this can't be manual and the deluge package is not requested by a program of mine, but from flexget package, that runs smoothly in this configuration.

I'm not experienced in pyenv and I can't find a simple way to setup a PYTHON_PATH under a pyenv virtualenv, or any other workaround that allows me to call deluge package in system's python under the virtualenv.

Any suggestions ?

TIA
Enrico

- Running from Ubuntu Server 12.04
- pyenv 20150326-483-g10d5d9a

Comment: It seems that your pip installation has access to some packages that the Python version that you're using doesn't. What do you get if you do `pip freeze -l` ?

Comment: Sorry, in these minutes, I changed the original config.
I managed to let python 2.7.9 see deluge by symlinking it into site-package.
It works now but it's not ideal.
If deluge would be available as pip package all this won't be necessary.

Comment: Is this the deluge that you are looking for? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deluge-client/1.0.2 if it is, you can do `pip install deluge-client` within your venv.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, but it's a different package.
I don't think that's it, but I can try.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the same package.
Flexget expects to find "deluge", not "deluge-client".
Is it possibile to repackage locally the deluge package found in system's dist to use it in a virtualenv ?

Answer (score 0):

The Python module `deluge` is installed to your system python when you `apt-get install deluged` I belive (I could be mistaken though).

Kinda sucks that this Python module `deluge` is not available via pip, but you should be able to install it into your virtualenv with the following:

First off, have your virtualenv of choice activated, then run

```
mkdir ~/my_lovely_directory && cd ~/my_lovely_directory
git clone git://deluge-torrent.org/deluge.git
cd deluge
git checkout -b 1.3-stable origin/1.3-stable
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

> Note: At this time of writing the Python module `deluge` is at version
>   1.3.13, if it is ~1.4 or higher at time of reading you might want to checkout different branch above, see list of branches with `git branch -a`.

You should now see a package called something like this `deluge (1.3.13.dev0)` when running `pip list` in your selected virtualenv.

If everything looks good you can clean up a bit with

```
cd ~/ && rm -rf ~/my_lovely_directory
```

Sources:

- [Installing Deluge From Source](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Installing/Source)
- [Git Source Code Repository](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/GitRepo)